# Pass dynamic parameter to javascript in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using `javascript` to set `hidden` field's values, I am passing those values from `javascript function`. Here is some code from `aspx`

```
<table>
    <% if (dtLevel1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dtLevel1.Rows)
                {
                    %><tr>
                        <td width="11%">
                            <img class="imgClass" alt="" src="/Styles/expand-large-silver-Shapes4FREE.png" height="11px"
                                onclick="meClick(this)" />
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <% if (dr["HaveChildren"].ToString() == "True")
                                        {
                                            string id = dr["LinkID"].ToString();
                            %>
                            <a onclick="showPopUp('l1',''dynamic value)"><span style="font-size: 18px">
                                <%= dr["LinkName"]%></span></a>
                            <%}
                                        else
                                        { %>
                            <span style="font-size: 18px">
                                <%= dr["LinkName"]%></span>
                            <%} %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% 
                }
            }
    %>
</table>
```

please have a look at these 2 lines:

1. `string id = dr["LinkID"].ToString();`
   id coming from `DataTable`. and I want to pass this value as a second parameter from this following code: 
   `<a onclick="showPopUp('l1',''dynamic value)">`

How can we do this?

I already tried

`<a onclick="showPopUp('l1','+"'"+id+"'"+')">`
and 
`<a onclick="showPopUp('l1',\'' + id + '\')">`
but did worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
<a onclick="showPopUp('l1','<%= dr["LinkID"].ToString() %>')">
```